# fetch actual url from the dynamic link in android

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an acitivity with different fragments.in my home fragment i have a slider.i will be getting the dynamic url while clicking the slider image.i need to open another fragment with respect to the query parameter in the dynamic link.
My problem is i cannot convert this dynamic url to actual url.

For example the dymanic link is https://x97av.app.goo.gl/AbCD..I need to convert this link to https://abcd.com/lmno/a?id=2..
So i could easily fetch the id and move to respective screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a hidden webview (not visible in UI) to load the dynamic URL, and use

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // here you can use the actual url.
    }
});
```

so, you can use the actual URL when the dynamic URL loaded.